# How can I check if user input is in a random string from a list?

Tags: python, list, variables, random, input

I am trying to program hangman. I am quite new and am wondering something. I already figured this out

```
 x = "Hello World"
print(x[2])
print(x[6])
print(x[10])
```

The output is

```
l
W
d
```

I am wondering if i can write this:

```
import random
list = ["Hi","Hello","Hi wrld","Hello world"]
chosen = list(random.randint(1,4)
nr_of_letters = len(chosen)
# j is the letter the user guesses
j = input()
if j == chosen[0,nr_of_letters]:
   print("something")
else:
   print("something else")
```

The error info I get is that the number has to be an integer. If I try writing it differently I have 2 options.

```
#the first option is :
j = int(input ())
#the second option is:
if j == chosen[0,int(nr_of_letters)]:
```

neither of them work. Please how can I write that correctly.

Comment: Try: `chosen = list[random.randint(0,3)]`

Answer (score 1):

So first, to choose a random word from a list:

```
import random
words = ["Hi","Hello","Hi wrld","Hello world"]
chosen = random.choice(words)
# Chosen will now be one of the words in the list
```

Since you're trying to code hangman I assume you know you'll need a while loop to allow the user to keep giving input so I'll just work with what you've given here as an example. So for checking if they entered a correct letter:

```
j = input()
if j in chosen:
    print("something")
else:
    print("something else")
```

Is that ok?